# changing to parent directory in unix

Tags: unix, shell, command-line, ksh

in general we use

`cd ..` for going to the parent directory

`cd ../../` to go to the parents parent directory. and

`cd ../../../../../` for 5th parent directory.

is there any simplified way of doing this?

shell i am  using is ksh.

Comment: You can leave off the slash at the end. Also, the answer to your question may depend on which shell.

Comment: Some shortcuts: `cd -` takes you back to wherever you just came from. `cd ~` takes you to your home directory.

Comment: You can checkout the new command '`bd`': see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18694331/6309)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This function is for Bash, but something similar could be done for others (this may work as-is in ksh and zsh):

```
cdn () { pushd .; for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++)); do cd ..; done; pwd; }
```

Example usage:

```
/some/dirs/and/subdirs$ cdn 3
/some/dirs/and/subdirs /some/dirs/and/subdirs
/some
/some$ popd
/some/dirs/and/subdirs$
```

Here's a function that will `cd` to a named subdirectory above the current working directory:

```
cdu () { cd "${PWD%/$1/*}/$1"; }
```

Example usage:

```
/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/src/generator$ cdu apm
/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm$ cdu resources
/usr/share/atom/resources$ cd -
/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm$ cdu share
/usr/share
```

Comment: i am accepting this since it seems we dont have a direct command line short cut for this.still i hope  there is some way to do it in short way on command line.

Comment: I really like the `cdu` function.  It is simple and only depends on `cd` and variable substitution.

Answer (score 6):

And I thought I was lazy...

Long ago, I got tired of typing `cd ..` so, since roughly 1988 one of my standard aliases (and batch files for MSDOS/Windows) is `up`.  Perhaps I should extend the concept:

```
alias up='cd ..'
alias up2='cd ../..'
alias up3='cd ../../..'
alias up4='cd ../../../..'
alias up5='cd ../../../../..'
alias up6='cd ../../../../../..'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful if you setup any aliases like this.  You will not always go up 5 directories when you `cd ../../../../..`.  If you are only 2 or 3 directories down from / you will wind up in /.  Try this for yourself.

```
$ cd ~
$ pwd
/home/you
$ cd ../../../..
$ pwd
/
```

This happens because the parent directory of / is in fact /.

Comment: this cannot be considered as answer rather it should be a comment.

Comment: How would you suggest a cautionary 'comment' such as this be written? It seemed like it merited vertical space for clarity.  Sometimes the real answer to a question is to figure out that you might not want to do things the way that you first thought you wanted to do things.  I hope your knowing that your 'cdn 5' might only be a 'cdn 1' might save you more than just a few dots.

Comment: So there are two parent marks; is there a way to set one yourself?

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the [recent project `bd`](https://github.com/vigneshwaranr/bd)

> If you are in this path

```
/home/user/project/src/org/main/site/utils/file/reader/whatever
```

and you want to go to `site` directory quickly (instead of typing `cd ../../../..`),
then just type:

```
bd site
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like typing or remembering file names, you can navigate directories with something like NerdTree?

Answer (score 0):

You could define aliases to simplify this kind of `cd` operation.

Note that it would be easy to make errors with an alias in terms of `../../../..` etc, because you would have to be *very sure of the relationship* between your current directory and where you wanted to be.

Better to use absolute paths with `alias`

Answer (score 0):

use `cd /` to go to the root of you filesystem, and `cd ~` to go to you home directory.
Example: to go to you log director just do `cd /var/log`.

Answer (score 0):

For Bourne-type shells (including `ksh`), you could write a shell function:

```
cdup() {
    set -- "${1-1}"
    while test "$1" -gt 0; do
      cd ..
      set -- "$(($1-1))"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally how I do it. Of course in ksh you may have your navigation keys set to something else. When I used ksh I used have them set to vi style so that would be `k` instead of up arrow.

In shell scripts it is better to be explicit. If you can use an absolute pathname then do so and run a command like:

```
cd /webdata/cgi-bin
```

If the script may be run to act on files in different directories, then you could consider something like this:

```
TOPDIR="/webdata"
cd $TOPDIR/cgi-bin
```

But if you really can't do either of those then stick to .. chains like so:

```
chmod +x *.py
cd ../../../cgi-bin
```

This is quite clear. Perform an action in the current working directory, then navigate up 3 levels and select the cgi-bin directory. Anyone who would be capable of understanding what you are doing in the shell script should have no difficulty in following this. If your script is really complex, then it would help to add some comments like this:

```
# change to TOPDIR/cartsys/production/code/python
cd python    
chmod +x *.py
cd ../../../cgi-bin
```

The implication is that you were in the code directory and changed down one level to python, therefore the reader who forgot where you were in the directory hierarchy sees a reminder to help them count up 3 levels.

```
cd ..

<up arrow><ENTER>
<up arrow><ENTER>
<up arrow><ENTER>
<up arrow><ENTER>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a shell utility for this use case: https://github.com/kkew3/cdup. As some examples:

- to go 4 directories upward, use `up -4`.
- to go to the nearest parent directory matching globbing pattern `site*`, use `up -g'site*'`.
- to go to the nearest parent directory matching regex `[pP]roj(ect)?`, use `up -E'[pP]roj(ect)?'`.