# bash script regex to get directory path up nth levels

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm using PWD to get the present working directory. Is there a SED or regex that I can use to, say, get the full path two parents up?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why sed or regex?  Why not `dirname`:

```
parent=`dirname $PWD`
grandparent=`dirname $parent`
```

**Edit:**

@Daentyh points out in the comments that apparently `$()` is preferred over backquotes ``` `` ``` for command substitution in POSIX-compliant shells. I don't have experience with them.  More info:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03

So, if this applies to your shell, you can (should?) use:

```
parent=$(dirname $PWD)
grandparent=$(dirname $parent)
```

Comment: You should use `$()` over `\`\`` since he specified bash.

Comment: @Daenyth - true, I was actually thinking of suggesting he retag the question (or allow me to retag it) to `sh` or `shell-scripting` since the question wasn't really `bash` specific. @Steve - what do you think?

Comment: Even so, `$()` is still POSIX sh. (Not all sh are POSIX though)

Comment: Further nag: You should quote PWD as `"$PWD"`, otherwise spaces in a directory name will break you. @Benoit's solution is far simpler though and will work anywhere without trouble. `dirname` is not entirely portable also.

Comment: Beware that grandparent of `./foo` will be `.`.

Comment: Loved this solution, I used this like `SERVICE_PATH=$(dirname $(dirname $(realpath $0)))` in a script that was inside a scripts folder and needed that to run in the parent and it just made my life easier. Thank you very much.

Comment: I dislike this, because going four levels up (which I need) spawns four recursive subshells, and is verbose. See the answer of Dennis Williamson, which is much better in my opinion.

Answer (score 22):

This should work in POSIX shells:

```
echo ${PWD%/*/*}
```

which will give you an absolute path rather than a relative one.

Also, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1872007/26428) where I give two functions:

```
cdn () { pushd .; for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++)); do cd ..; done; pwd; }
```

which goes up *n* levels given *n* as an argument.

And:

```
cdu () { cd "${PWD%/$1/*}/$1"; }
```

which goes up to a named subdirectory above the current working directory.

Comment: This should be the answer. This is more reusable than accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

why not use

```
"${PWD}/../.."
```

?

Comment: I prefer this simple approach. `realpath "${PWD}/../.."` and it should be much safer than regex especially when dealing with non-ascii languages.

Answer (score 2):

Not sed or regex, but this does do arbitrary parent quantity:

```
$ cd $(mktemp -dp $(mktemp -dp $(mktemp -dp $(mktemp -d)))) && \
> n=3 && \
> readlink -f  ${PWD}/$(for i in $(seq ${n}); do echo -n '../' ; done)
/tmp/tmp.epGcUeLV9q
```

In this example, I `cd` into a 5-deep temporary directory, assign `n=3`, construct a relative path `n` levels up from `${PWD}`, and `-f, --canonicalize` the result with `readlink`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex that works for me.  It's a little different between grep and Perl/sed:

The extended regex breaks up paths into 0 or more groups of `/ABC123` anchored to the end of line, *essentially working backward*.  `(.*)` consumes everything prior to this match and replaces it.

```
user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd
/home/user/adir/bdir

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | perl -pe 's|(.*)((/.*?){0})$|\1|'
/home/user/adir/bdir

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | perl -pe 's|(.*)((/.*?){1})$|\1|'
/home/user/adir

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | sed -r 's|(.*)((/.*?){2})$|\1|'
/home/user

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | sed -r 's|(.*)((/.*?){3})$|\1|'
/home

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | sed -r 's|(.*)((/.*?){4})$|\1|'
```

Grep can simulate substitution using a positive look ahead `(?=` which tells grep to match everything except the pattern.  `-Po` tells grep to use Perl regex and show only the match.

```
user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd
/home/user/adir/bdir

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | grep -Po '(.*)(?=((/.*?){0})$)'
/home/user/adir/bdir

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | grep -Po '(.*)(?=((/.*?){1})$)'
/home/user/adir

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | grep -Po '(.*)(?=((/.*?){2})$)'
/home/user

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | grep -Po '(.*)(?=((/.*?){3})$)'
/home

user@home:~/adir/bdir$ pwd | grep -Po '(.*)(?=((/.*?){4})$)'
```

Of course it works equally well for Windows style paths:

```
C:\home\user\adir\bdir> cd
C:\home\user\adir\bdir

C:\home\user\adir\bdir> cd | perl -pe 's|(.*)((\\.*?){0})$|\1|'
C:\home\user\adir\bdir

C:\home\user\adir\bdir> cd | sed -r 's|(.*)((\\.*?){1})$|\1|'
C:\home\user\adir

C:\home\user\adir\bdir> cd | grep -Po '(.*)(?=((\\.*?){2})$)'
C:\home\user

C:\home\user\adir\bdir> cd | grep -Po '(.*)(?=((\\.*?){3})$)'
C:\home

C:\home\user\adir\bdir> cd | grep -Po '(.*)(?=((\\.*?){4})$)'
C:
```

Sorry for the edits but I've been working on this enigma for about 16 hours now.  Just kept trying different permutations and re-reading the regex docs.  It had to sink in eventually.